# How can add controller in ASP.NET MVC6 beta5 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc

i'm install `Visual Studio 2015` final release and create `mvc6 beta5` project (by default template). 
Trying add controller as in `mvc 5.2` (also in vs2015 final release):
[image: in mvc 5.2]

but, in `mvc6 beta5` project this menu missing:
[image: in mvc 6]

**1. How solve the problem?**

**UPD**

**2. Is it possible add mvc6 controller with generate views?**
[image: generate views]

Comment: Come one, a controller is just a class. Create a new class and name it controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to MVC 6.0 the notion of an MVC Controller and a Web API Controller were somewhat different. To the untrained eye, they looked similar but they did behave differently and were using different classes.

Hence why when you clicked the `Controller…` option, you had the ability to choose between an MVC Controller and/or a Web API Controller.

As of MVC 6.0, both MVC and Web API controllers have now been `unified`. They are now exactly the same thing and are using the same classes.

So you don’t really have the need to choose between an MVC Controller and a Web API Controller.

Simply click the Add New Item which in turn will open the Add New Item dialog.

From the Add New Item dialog in the top right search textbox, enter *Controller*.

You’ll be able to select the `MVC Controller Class` template.

Who knows...maybe by the time they ship the final product, they’ll bring it back but at least for now, this shouldn’t be a show stopper.

EDIT:
For the scaffolding stuff, perhaps this [link](https://chad.tolkien.id.au/asp-net-vnext-mvc6-ground-up-4-crud-in-mvc/) might help.

Comment: Ahhhh...yes, that's different. You want the auto-generated stuff to happen as well. In that case, I don't believe it is possible as of this writing. Perhaps when the final product is shipped, then you'll have the scaffolding stuff.

Comment: yes, i want to have vs generate (controllers, views) tool.

Comment: This answer is not correct. The MVC and WebAPI classes do not share all of the same code classes. As of the current VS you can create the MVC controller from scratch, which of course makes little sense, but it works. The question was if the scaffolding is auto-generated, and sadly, as of now, that is not the case.

Comment: I´ve been trying the new Community edition 2015, and have sme problem. No Add Controller wizard, no views wizard, and right now it would be useful to have the strong typed templates for lists and so on for an adminsitration page I need. So back to 4.5.2 templates? or something else?

Comment: How much of this scaffolding/wizard stuff a show stopper for you? Can’t you manually create a Controller and a View that is strongly typed to an IEnumerable<> for example, and then simply use that as a template. In other words, copy/paste the Controller and/or View whenever you want and simply change the stuff that needs to be changed (like the ViewModel). Could you consider this until the scaffolding stuff shows up in VS 2015?

Answer (score 0):

to solve this go to project.json
then add the following dependency:
"Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final"

then you should be able to right click controllers folder and see the new controller button appear

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue for ***visual studio 2015 community*** edition, followed following steps and restarted visual studio. It resolved my issue

- 1)Open VS2015=>TOOLS=>Customize.
- 2)Select Commands.
- 3)Select Context menu.
- 4)Select Project and Solution ContextMenus|Folder|Add.
- 5)Check that 'Controller' appears.
- 6)IMPORTANT -Move up Controller item to the top.
- 7)Restart visual studio