# Add view Menu is missing Visual Studio 2015. Not able to add View by right clicking the controller method

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to .net. I have created simple .net core mvc web project.

I have created view by just right clicking on the controller name in asp mvc project.

Here in this project I am not able to do that. When I right click on the controller method. I don't find the "Add View" menu item.

Please suggest how to add view page. I need a short cut

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can add controller in ASP.NET MVC6 beta5 project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538172/how-can-add-controller-in-asp-net-mvc6-beta5-project)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, go to `project.json` and add the following dependency:

```
 "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
 "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
```

then you should be able to right click controllers folder and see the new controller/new scaffold button appear and below are options available-

[image: Add Scaffold]

From these options, you can select MVC View where you can create View based on model like this-

[image: Add View]